# how to parse html tags in crm body

Tags: html, dynamics-crm-2011

I have and html img tag,such as

```
<html>
    <head>
        <img border="0" title="FashionAndYou" alt="FashionAndYou" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/jt20Wtw88V402X02wMfXh7njafZj3OAP4ufMMeYIsGrjHlBs5Litrq5az3eRa2TWDl3tNDMUPObE3VgFZBCJjTBIR2gaQunZhIk9pmmhMkEl1EaWqA">
    </head>
</html>
```

how to parse this image tag exactly in crm 2011 workflow send email body.
when i run the workflow on demand, the mail doesn't parse the html tag.Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

The email editor does not allow all tags. You should consider writing a pre create plug-in. 
In the plug-in you can set the description field with any html you desire.
Another choice is to include a placeholder in the WF template / email and replace it with the html tags, but don’t include the head and body tags unless this is the entire email.